# HTML Button Change Image Source

Tags: html, image, button

Okay, I was wondering if this is possible. 
I want an image, and a totally separate button. When the button is clicked, I would like the Img Src to change from "images/test" to "images/test2"

Is this possible?

Let's just say I have a very simple site, with just an image and a button

```
 <html> 
<head>...
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/test"/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<button>Click to change image!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I change this very simple HTML to do what I want?

Comment: use background in css and hover effect or javascript event

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your `img` tag is not closed in your code. 
Secondly, you can change the image `src` on click of the button using simple javascript or jQuery.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 

function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src="images/test2";
return false;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="images/test" />
<br><br><br>
<button id="clickme" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change image!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you!